# CSS, why are these div's piling on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

Basicly I would like these 4 buttons to seperate with a width of 5px between them? When I had my position as relative it worked fine but when I put it to absolute they each pile on top of each other? Why is this and does anyone know a fix? Thanks.

Code:

```
#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 505px;
    width: 860;
    height: 560px;
}

#content ul li
{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 2px;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    padding: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
}
```

Example (Buttons in the top left.):
[image]

Comment: That's because you are giving them absolute positioning.. this makes all of them at the same x, y position from the screen

Comment: How would I separate them then?

Comment: Gotta say, absolute positioning is probably your **worst** option here.

Comment: Use different `left` values

Comment: what is wrong with position:relative?

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning unless you know why you need to. Use floats or inline-block for layouts instead.

Comment: If you want them vertically positioned leave them as is and add a margin top to li.. if you want them horizontally positioned give float left or right to the li in addition to margin left or right.. give me more clarification of what you want and I can write you a code example.

Comment: You should at least take the time to learn CSS basics before posting questions here

Comment: margin-left: 5px; is exactly what yo want after making position: relative;

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, I have now changed it and it works, but instead they are in a column, how would I make them a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN page on positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning):

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

They are piling up on top of each other because no space is reserved for them in the flow of the page.